# How to open the third tab bar item when my application launches?

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem, appdelegate

I'm working on a tab bar application with five items in it and I want to open the third view controller which is associated to the third tab bar item when my application launches instead of the first one which opens by default. How can I approach this?

Here's the code I'm using:

In myappdelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet   FirstViewController *firstView;
```

In myappdelegate.m

```
[window addSubView:firstView.view];
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use bellow code to display the 3 tab of UITabBar at first...

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks , I will give your answer and the other a try when I have a chance.

Comment: no problem , post comment if you get any query.. and for display 3 tab at application launch then just use this only one line after you assign tabbarcontroller as a rootviewcontroller for window...

Comment: I do not have chance to try it right now because I'm away of my desk but I will let you know if there is any issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the viewWillAppear method of that viewController set the visible tab:

```
self.yourTabBarController.selectedViewController = [yourTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods above but if you want it to happen with the application launches you need to use `-(void) awakeFromNib {` That function is called when you press the app icon on your devices home screen.
viewDidLoad is called after your Default.png has been displayed.